# Getting NativeModule.RNPermission is null; Using react-native-jitsi-meet on android

Tags: react-native

Using react-native-jitsi-meet and as soon as I call JitsiMeet.call() I am getting a crash on android. I am getting these errors on the android studio logcat:
react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform
&
Error: react-native-permissions: NativeModule.RNPermissions is null.

Please suggest how to fix this crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by remaking the bundle file at

> android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

Comment: How we can remake the bundle? Please guide

Comment: react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

Answer (score 0):

When you use a navigator (such as stack navigator), you'll need to follow the installation instructions of that navigator for any additional dependencies. If you're getting an error "Unable to resolve module", you need to install that module in your project.

This will be helpful
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I resolved the issue by remaking the bundle file at /android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

Comment: If you don't mind can I know for what purpose you are using jitsimeet?

Comment: For Video Conferencing, ofc @Anandeva